# App of image detection in xamarin

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin

I want to make an app of image recognition and i need help of where to start. What i need is someone to explain me these few things

1. Wich offline libraries are the best to use with xamarin for image processing
2. in case more performance is needed, best libraries for Image processing iOS and Android to work them separately.

It does not matter if the library is in C or C++ what i want is documentation to follow

My idea of best is.
Well documented.
Easy to implement on the platforms xamarin or individually

The main functions i am looking for are for object recognition in an image NOT at runtime with camera

Also i want to add if is there any well document of fundamentals of image procesing and edge detection.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do - image detection is a big topic.

A couple of places to start are:

**Microsoft cognitive services**
https://blog.xamarin.com/performing-ocr-for-ios-android-and-windows-with-microsoft-cognitive-services/

This is an on-line service and can do OCR, facial recognition, even describing what is in an image.

**OpenCV**

This is a fully featured computer vision library available in C++ with iOS and Android wrappers you can bind to use form Xamarin.

http://opencv.org